# Can't alter brightness on Dell XPS 15 9570 OLED (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, brightness

I cannot change my laptop's screen brightness via keyboard shortcuts or the slider in Gnome's drop down settings. I have tried Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04, and PopOS.

I have tried every solution I could find on Dell's forum, Reddit, and SuperUser and none of them have worked. Most solutions propose a change to /etc/default/grub of which I have tried every combination I could find but none work. I did not forget to run "sudo update-grub".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After much searching I found the answer. The problem is related to the fact the screen has no backlight (because it's OLED).

Install xbacklight and run this command:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1   # no dimming
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .5  # dim to half
```

If this doesn't work change eDP1 to eDP-1

This AskUbuntu page has more info:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/897655/cant-control-the-display-brightness-on-lenovo-x1-yoga-oled